# Python3 giving syntax error for some reason for single quote

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I have a Python3 script that exports a CSV file to a MYSQL RDS Server. Below is the line of the code that gives me syntax error due some reason I am not able to debug it at all. Python Version Python 3.5.3

```
def connect_to_db():
    connection_string = f'mysql+pymysql://{USR}:{PWD}@{ENDPOINT}:{PORT}/{DBNAME}'
    logger.debug(f'Create DB Connection with string - {connection_string}')
    try:
        engine = create_engine(connection_string)
        logger.info("Connected successfully")
        return engine
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
        return None
```

Below image shows the error. I tried both combination single and double quote same error.

[image]

Comment: Which python version you are using?. If I am correct `f-strings` are introduced from python3.6 on wards.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Python 3.5.3

Comment: I'm using Python 3.8; the parser has no trouble with this code.  Please note that we expect a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  There should be no reason to include the **try - except** block.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM is right, the `f` notation is the problem in the version `3.5.3`. Running it in python 3.6 or higher it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f` strings are [introduced from **Python 3.6**](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-features) onwards.  If you want to use the `f` string syntax in your current python version you can use [future-fstrings](https://github.com/asottile/future-fstrings) which is a backport of fstrings to python<3.6.

Alternatively you can also use the [advanced string formatting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)

```
>>> 'mysql+pymysql://{USR}:{PWD}@{ENDPOINT}:{PORT}/{DBNAME}'.format(USR="testuser", PWD="password", ENDPOINT="endpoint", PORT=123, DBNAME="name")
'mysql+pymysql://testuser:password@endpoint:123/name'
```